# How to extract values from an ESRI shapefile in R

Tags: r, raster, r-raster, r-sp

I am trying to extract proportional landcover values from several USFWS National Wetlands Inventory shapefiles within buffer zones around a spatial points data frame. When plotted in QGIS, the shapefiles contain numerous polygons representing wetlands, each with a different classification. My goal is to convert this shapefile to a Formal Class Raster Layer and extract these values using raster::extract().

I have calculated proportional landcover for buffered points successfully in unison with library(FedData) and get_nlcd(); however, I have been completely unsuccessful when trying to work with ESRI .shp files. Every time I have tried to follow someone else's instructions on how to rasterize shapefiles, the extracted dataframe is full of null values. I'm not sure if I am missing a step, or if it is just the nature of the shapefile I am working with, but I was hoping someone could offer a solution.

```
library(sp)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
#making a spatial data frame from coordinates
coords = cbind(SeniorThesisSamples$Longitude, SeniorThesisSamples$Latitude)
points_spdf = SpatialPoints(coords, proj4string = crs("+proj=aea +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83"))

#Extending spatial extent to make sure all points can have an X km buffer -----------------
r = raster(ncol = 3, nrow = 3)
extent(r) =  extent(points_spdf) * 1.5
crs(r) = crs(points_spdf)

#read in National Wetlands Inventory ESRI shapefile
RI.nwi <- raster::shapefile("~/Documents/Senior Thesis Stuff/NWI Shapefiles/RI_shapefile_wetlands/RI_Wetlands.shp")

# Transform .shp to match CRS of the spdf
RI.nwi <- spTransform(RI.nwi, crs(r))

#creating an empty raster with the extent of my spdf and setting resolution to 100m
empty.raster <- raster(extent(r), res = 100)
crs(empty.raster) = crs(r)
RI.nwi.raster <- rasterize(RI.nwi, empty.raster)

#extracting raster values at a set buffer distance and put into data frame
wetlands1km <- raster::extract(x = RI.nwi.raster, y = points_spdf, buffer = 1000, df = T)

#this part I know works because I have used it effectively to extract NLCD data
detach(package:plyr) # this is so the n() works
prop.wetlands1km <- as.data.frame(wetlands1km) %>%
  setNames(c("ID", "class")) %>%
  group_by(ID, class) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  mutate(pland = n / sum(n)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  dplyr::select(ID, class, pland) %>% # keep only these vars
  tidyr::complete(ID, nesting(class), fill = list(pland = 0)) %>% # Fill in implicit landcover 0s
  tidyr::spread(class, pland)
```

The code runs, but I am left with an empty data frame that should (from previous experience with NLCD data) have landcover classifications as the column headers and percent values in each cell.

I downloaded several state-level shapefiles from this link (https://www.fws.gov/wetlands/Data/State-Downloads.html) for reference. The points in my spdf extend beyond just Rhode Island, but it was the simplest shapefile to use because it's so small. Bonus points to anyone that can help me figure out a way to merge several of these state shapefiles together (ME, NH, MA, RI, CT, NY, NJ, DE, MD, VA) so that I can run the value extraction in one go! Any help is much appreciated!

EDIT: Attached is some requested sample code

```
> dput(head(SeniorThesisSamples))
structure(list(SiteName = c("Quonochontaug", "Quonochontaug", 
"Quonochontaug", "Quonochontaug"), State = c("RI", "RI", "RI", 
"RI"), SiteID = c("220450_p3", "220450_p3", "220450_p3", "220450_p3"
), Latitude = c(41.3335569999999, 41.3335569999999, 41.3335569999999, 
41.3335569999999), Longitude = c(-71.7167649999999, -71.7167649999999, 
-71.7167649999999, -71.7167649999999), Species = c("SALS", "SALS", 
"SALS", "SALS"), BandNum = c(278184716, 278184718, 278184721, 
278184715), HgConcentration = c(0.422, 0.32, 0.374, 0.309), Month = c(7, 
7, 7, 7), Day = c(29, 29, 29, 29), Year = c(2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018), Date = structure(c(17741, 17741, 17741, 17741), class = "Date")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L))

> RI.nwi
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 55398 
extent      : 1960230, 2051242, 2271966, 2388062  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0 
variables   : 5
names       : ATTRIBUTE,                     WETLAND_TY,        ACRES,   Shape_Leng,   Shape_Area 
min values  :    E1AB1L, Estuarine and Marine Deepwater, 1.000117e+00, 1.000005e+02, 1.000025e+03 
max values  :     R5UBH,                       Riverine, 9.998890e-03, 9.999467e+01, 9.999969e+02 

> head(RI.nwi)
  ATTRIBUTE                     WETLAND_TY     ACRES Shape_Leng Shape_Area
0     E2ABM   Estuarine and Marine Wetland 0.5421139   192.1974   2193.857
1     E2ABM   Estuarine and Marine Wetland 0.4598518   197.5223   1860.954
2     E2ABM   Estuarine and Marine Wetland 2.9291088   453.6280  11853.683
3    E2AB3M   Estuarine and Marine Wetland 2.0402979   514.5920   8256.793
4    E1AB1L Estuarine and Marine Deepwater 6.3219543   780.8088  25584.041
5    E1AB1L Estuarine and Marine Deepwater 2.0643299   361.9401   8354.047
```

Comment: Do you need to convert them to rasters? Or could you calculate areas from the shapefiles and use them to calculate proportions? Can you provide some sample data for people to try with (i.e., `dput(head(SeniorThesisSamples))`, `RI_Wetlands.shp`)?

Comment: please provide some simple example data generated by code, or from polygon data that comes with the `raster` package. For example `p <- shapefile(system.file("external/lux.shp", package="raster"))`. Do not use dput, that does not really work that well with spatial data. It is your responsibility to ask a crisp question that others can easily answer or learn from.  As Steward Macdonald hinted; you really should not use rasterize to begin with. Also, the file format is irrelevant --- so it is better to not refer to "shapefile", but rather to polygons, or `SpatialPolygons`.

Comment: @StewartMacdonald @RobertHijmans I attached the sample data you both requested at the bottom of the original post. Please let me know if  my edit didn't meet your expectations or you need additional info — I would be more than happy to email you the actual files. I originally tried ```wetlands1km <- extract(x = RI.nwi, y = points_spdf, buffer = 1000, df = T) ``` when RI.nwi was still a ```SpatialPolygonsDataFrame```, but it returns a single ATTRIBUTE value for each point which doesn't allow me to calculate proportional landcover.